# Counter-example for the fact that infimum of a function in a family of lower semi-continuous is not lower semi-continuous

Tags: general-topology

I'm sort of stuck with this question.

If we have a family of $(F_i)_{i\in I}$ lower semi-continuous functions (over a Hausdorff space) then I have already shown that $\sup_i \; F_i$ must be lower semi-continuous for any $i$.

Now I am tasked to find a counterexample for the case of $\inf_i \;F_i$, meaning to find a family of lower semi-continuous functions such that the infimum is not lower semi-continuous.

This leaves me somewhat perplexed though, because I have the feeling I can apply the same proof I made for the supremum case, but this must mean that my proof is somehow wrong (or I don't fully understand my own proof).

What I did was simply

$$
\sup_i F_i(x) \leq \sup_i \; (\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_i(x_n)) = \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_i F_i(x_n)
$$

due to continuity (?) of $\liminf$ I guess? Now that I write it down it looks so simplistic that it has to be wrong.

Now regarding the first question, what type of functions would I need to find in order to get a counterexample? I really don't know.

Comment: Consider the sign function with $f(0) = 1.$ Can you write this function as an infimum of continuous (actually Lipschitz) functions?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interchange the sup with the lim inf. Consider a sequence $(f_i)_{i\in N}$ of continuous real functions, where $f_i(0)=0$  and $f_i(1/i)=i$ for all $i\in N.$ For $n\in N$ let $x_n=1/n.$ Then for each $i$ we have $\lim \inf_{n\to \infty}f_i(x_n)=0.$ But  for each $n\in N$ we have $\sup_{i\in N}f_i(x_n)=1.$